# JQuery validator specific position for specific error from specific rule (errorPlacement doesn't reposition the errors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I would like the have a different position for a specific error on a specific field.
What i tried was the next bit, but errorPlacement only positions the error label correctly only the first time and keeps that position, making its content empty when the validation error is fixed. (so it doesn't re-position the label error only if previously removed manually from dom)

```js
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  if (error.text() == 'specific error from a specific rule') {
    ///position error in the bottom off the form
  }
  else {
    //position error in the default place as for all field errors
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... positions the error label correctly only the first time and keeps that position...

Yes, that's because the default behavior is to insert the error message element and toggle it for all subsequent errors.  That's just how the plugin is designed.